# How to start app when headset connected to phone in java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

How could start app or activity when headphone or headset connected to mobile it's possible ?  i read some example in another site about broadcast receiver.i'm new in android developing thanks if write example.

```
private class MusicIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) {
            int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);
            switch (state) {
                case 0:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "unplug", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "plug", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                default:

            }
        }



public class MusicIntentReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG)) {
            int state = intent.getIntExtra("state", -1);
            switch (state) {
                case 0:
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, "unplug", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Toast.makeText(ctx, "plug", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but this code work when application is running.

Comment: have you registered broadcast receiver in menifest with intent filter.

Comment: <receiver android:name=".MusicIntentReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT" />

                <category android:name="com.voice" />
            </intent-filter> @DheerubhaiBansal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this permission to your manifest file.

```
<receiver
    android:name="AudioJackReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.HEADSET_PLUG" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```